# How to format table notes with longtable + threeparttablex?

Tags: longtable, threeparttable, threeparttablex

With `threeparttable` and the regular `tabular` environment I was able to achieve the formatting of a custom note (flush left, spanning the entire width of the table, no label, while keeping the table footnotes indented) by adding it *outside* of the `tablenotes` environment (but within the `threeparttable` environment, see code below and table 1 in the screenshot).

Now I am trying to replicate this formatting with the combination `threeparttablex` + `longtable` but I am struggling to achieve the same effect. The only viable option so far seems to be adding it below `insertTableNotes`. But then the custom note would be treated as a normal row that increases the table width instead of being wrapped:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for replicating the formatting from table 1 without manually specifying the table width?

*Note:* The reasons why I am not using the `\note` command or the `flushleft` option from `threeparttablex` are that 1) I would like to be able to pass a note without label and 2) `flushleft` doesn't perfectly left-align the text.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c }
      \toprule
        type & cyl & disp & hp & drat & mpg\\
      \midrule
        Ferrari & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9  & 3.2\\
        VW & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9 & 3.7 \\
        Chevrolet & 4\tnote{a} & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 3.5\\
        Tesla & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 \\
        Ford & 8 & 360 & 175\tnote{b} & 3.15 & 32.6 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \item [a] A note that might as well span multiple rows despite being a footnote.
        \item [b] Another short note.
    \end{tablenotes}
    Here is some other stuff outside the tablenotes environment that might span multiple lines.
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{center}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
    \item [a] A note that might as well span multiple rows despite being a footnote.
    \item [b] Another short note.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{l c c c c c }
\caption{longtable}\\
  \toprule
    type & cyl & disp & hp & drat & mpg\\
  \midrule
    Ferrari & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9  & 3.2\\
    VW & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9 & 3.7 \\
    Chevrolet & 4\tnote{a} & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 3.5\\
    Tesla & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 \\
    Ford & 8 & 360 & 175\tnote{b} & 3.15 & 32.6 \\
    \bottomrule
  \insertTableNotes\\
  \footnotesize
  Here is some other stuff... but it will be treated as a normal row and not be confined to the table width.
\end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `longtblr` environment of the tabularray package to achieve the 2 effects you have mentioned in the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewTblrTheme{MyTheme}{
    \DefTblrTemplate{remark}{MyTmp}{
        \DefTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{MyTag}{}
        \DefTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{MyTag}{}
        \DefTblrTemplate{remark-text}{MyTag}{\InsertTblrRemarkText}
        \MapTblrRemarks{%
        \noindent
        \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{MyTag}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{MyTag}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{MyTag}
        \par
        }
    }

    \SetTblrTemplate{remark}{MyTmp}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = MyTheme,
    caption = {longtable},
    label = {tab:long},
    note{a} = {A note that might as well span multiple rows despite being a footnote.},
    note{b} = {Another short note.},
    remark{} = {Here is some other stuff... but it will be treated as a normal row and not be confined to the table width.},
]{%
    colspec = {lccccc},
    rowhead = 2,
}
    \toprule
    type & cyl & disp & hp & drat & mpg\\
    \midrule
    Ferrari & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9  & 3.2\\
    VW & 6 & 160 & 110 & 3.9 & 3.7 \\
    Chevrolet & 4\TblrNote{a} & 108 & 93 & 3.85 & 3.5\\
    Tesla & 6 & 258 & 110 & 3.08 \\
    Ford & 8 & 360 & 175\TblrNote{b} & 3.15 & 32.6 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I used the default `TblrNote` command to insert usual table notes. To add the custom note I changed the `remark` template and inserted that as a new theme.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had actually come across the tabularray package but stayed away from it because it wouldn't compile (being Latex3). Now I found out that the regular Overleaf will compile it if you choose the newest Tex Live distribution (2021) while my university's Overleaf/sharelatex distribution still only offers the 2020 edition.

Comment: @dufei You can compile with 2020 edition if you add the sty file in your working project (though I am not sure if it is possible to add an sty file while using your university's distribution). You may find the sty file [here](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/blob/main/tabularray.sty).

Comment: That works indeed! Now I will need to wrap my head around the new syntax (e.g., how to change the font for the superscript letters) but the documentation seems quite good. Thanks again!

Comment: I think all table related things can be done using only this package. So, learning this package is a worth shot.